# Remove item from gridView, but in Tablet show that deleted last item.How to fix this?

Tags: android, gridview, arraylist

I add item into gridView (use ArrayList with 10 items), but when I click button to remove item (for ex. item index of 2), it remove correct item from ArrayList but in gridView remove last one.

This is Adapter getView()
`

```
    public View getView(int arg0, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {

    View row = convertView; OrderItemHolder holder;
    OrderItem mItem = orderItemsList.get(arg0);

    if (row == null) {

        isNew = true;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) orderActivity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_item, arg2, false);

        holder = new OrderItemHolder();
        // initialize the elements
        holder.itemOrderRLay = (RelativeLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.itemOrderRLay);

        holder.orderItemImage = (CImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.orderItemImage);

        holder.itemCount = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemCount);
        holder.itemCount.setId(mItem.getCountId());

        holder.itemText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
        holder.itemCost = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemCost);

        holder.maxCount = (CButton) row.findViewById(R.id.maxCount);
        holder.maxCount.setCountViewId(holder.itemCount.getId());

        holder.minCount = (CButton) row.findViewById(R.id.minCount);
        holder.minCount.setCountViewId(holder.itemCount.getId());

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (OrderItemHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    if (mItem != null) {
        if(isNew){

            isNew = false;

            holder.itemCount.setText("x" + mItem.getCount());
            //holder.itemCount.setId(mItem.getCountId());

            holder.itemText.setText(mItem.getMenuInsideItem().getName());
            holder.itemText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.small_title_bg);

            holder.itemCost.setText("(" + mItem.getMenuInsideItem().getTime() + " dəq | " + mItem.getMenuInsideItem().getCost() + " manat)");

            holder.itemCost.setTextColor(Color.rgb(93, 40, 40));

            Drawable d = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(mItem.getMenuInsideItem().getPicId());
            holder.orderItemImage.setImageBitmap(OrderUtil.roundCornerImage(OrderUtil.drawableToBitmap(d), 9));

            holder.maxCount.setIndex(arg0);         
            holder.maxCount.setOnClickListener(this);

            holder.minCount.setIndex(arg0);
            holder.minCount.setOnClickListener(this);


            holderList.add(holder);
        }
    }

    return row;
}`
```

gridView item xml code

`

```
                        <emenu.custom.CImageView
                            android:id="@+id/orderItemImage"
                            android:layout_width="165dp"
                            android:layout_height="165dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/image_bg_thin"
                            android:clickable="false"
                            android:minWidth="50dip"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/a10" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/itemCost"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/orderItemImage"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/orderItemImage"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="deq|mnt"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <emenu.custom.CButton
                            android:id="@+id/minCount"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/maxCount"
                            android:background="@drawable/image_bg_full"
                            android:text="-"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                        <emenu.custom.CButton
                            android:id="@+id/maxCount"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/orderItemImage"
                            android:background="@drawable/image_bg_full"
                            android:text="+"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/itemText"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_above="@+id/itemCount"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/orderItemImage"
                            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/orderItemImage"
                            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/orderItemImage"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Pasta Florentine Casserole"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="13sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/itemCount"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_above="@+id/itemCost"
                            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/itemCost"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="x1"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="24sp" />

</RelativeLayout>`
```

And button click function `

```
        case R.id.minCount: countText = (TextView) holder.itemOrderRLay.findViewById(holder.minCount.getCountViewId());

        count = OrderUtil.updateDBCount((int) mItem.getMenuInsideItem().getId(), deviceId, mItem.getCountId(), mContext, false);

        Log.w(TAG, "(line 179) button.getIndex() = " + button.getIndex());
        Log.w(TAG, "(line 180) holder.minCount.getCountViewId() = " + holder.minCount.getCountViewId());
        Log.w(TAG, "(line 181) count = " + count);
        Log.w(TAG, "(line 182) holder.getIndex() = " + holderList.indexOf(holder));

        if(count != 0){         
            countText.setText("x" + count);                             
        }

        if(count == 0){
            OrderUtil.updateDBCount((int) mItem.getMenuInsideItem().getId(), deviceId, mItem.getCountId(), mContext, false);
            Log.w(TAG, "(line 192) button.getIndex() = " + button.getIndex());


            orderItemsList.remove(button.getIndex());

            this.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        totalCost -= mItem.getMenuInsideItem().getCost();
        totalCostText.setText(totalCost + " manat");
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that after `notifyDataSetChanged()` views, that are used in gridview, are not recycled, so in `getView()` no new views are created and the isNew equals false. This way nothing is changed until theese views will be destroyed. The last item is not shown , because `getView()` got called so many times as the number of items, which was reduced. So, you should remove `isNew` check.

Comment: What is the purpose of `isNew`?

Comment: BTW, after the removal turn off and on the screen, to check if it will  become correct.

Comment: `isNew` used for to prevent repeated getView functions. I dont know why,but getView called more times,and repeat existed items.

Comment: I check ArrayList by Log. No problem, list remove correct item but visually removed last in gridView.

Comment: And when I re-open activity where `gridView` exist, I see true items.

Comment: I have updated my answer, the problem seems to be because of `isNew`.
`"I dont know why,but getView called more times,and repeat existed items"` - do you mean that there more items in gridView, then in the adapter in that case? Are you sure you return correct number in `getCount()`?

Comment: I mean that holder get existed item when I want to create a new one of `OrderItem ` object. Yes I am sure, because I check every stem,when I click to button, when update db etc. Absolutely everything is correct, but only what I see in tablet is wrong.

Comment: GridView and ListView can reuse views, that were previously used in other "cells" or "rows", so it is normal behaviour. You should just remove `isNew` and it will work, I suppose.

Comment: I test it, but without `isNew` it not work. I dont know how to explain (((( Generally is exist working exampe ,that remove item from given index of gridView. Can you help me?

Comment: That is strange, it should work without isNew. 
You can try spiky solution: in spite of `this.notifyDataSetChanged();` set:
`List<OrderItem> tmp = orderItemsList;
 orderItemsList = new List<OrderItem>();
 this.notifyDataSetChanged();
 orderItemsList = tmp;
 this.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: I have bad news, not worked. Tzoiker which different between `ListView `and `GridView`. Because when I use `ListView `the minus button work true, but I want to show items as 2 or more columns, because that I change view to `GridView`. but know its problem which I cannot solve.

Comment: May be, I can try help, If you try to explain what is the problem without `isNew`.

BTW, what is the purpose of the holderList?